# Python: Google App Engine , JavaScript Channel API to call back end

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Hi I am quite new to java script and i am looking a working example to call back ends using java script channel API . I do not have any idea about channel API . Can anyone provide me a working example

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close this before I saw the reference to backends. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to get a message from the backend to a javascript client: you can't send messages from a backend server to a channel created on a frontend server. This is because the app version number is included in the channel token, and backends have a different app version than frontends. You could, however, implement a servlet in your backend that calls createChannel and returns it to your frontend for inclusion in javascript that your frontend renders.

If you're trying to send a message to a backend from your javascript code, you won't be able to use XmlHttpRequest directly because of the same-origin policy (this assumes your clients are rendered from a non-backend instance). You could get around this using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), or by routing XHR requests from your frontend to your backend in a frontend servlet.

Comment: I have a back end handler which fetch URLs . I am looking a way to call it  via an ajax Handler. That is my goal

Comment: and i am looking for a python example

Answer (score 2):

Did you see the docs? [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html) / [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html)

Comment: Im Using python not java . it didnt specify anything about backend urls though used URL;s

Comment: See this : http://netgamix.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/a-simple-chat-using-the-channel-api/

Comment: @pradeek the site you mentioned is "a protected blog" and I don't want to login to wordpress.