# How do I send a Channel API token created in a backend on a push queue to the front end in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend, channel-api

I am trying to send Channel API messages from a GAE python backend push queue to a client.  The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292540/python-google-app-engine-javascript-channel-api-to-call-back-end) says that the channel must be created within the back-end process in order to be able to send messages from the backend to the client.  The answer suggests that

> "You could, however, implement a servlet in your backend that calls createChannel and returns it to your frontend for inclusion in javascript that your frontend renders."

My question is: How do I get the token created by the backend in a push queue to the front end so that I can send the token to the client?  I create the backend push queue using the following:

```
taskqueue.Task(url='/flow/', params = {'json_request': json_request}, target='flowbackend').add(queue_name='flow-queue')
```

and I have not been able to figure how to easily send information back to the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda weird that you want to create a channel in your backend.
The most obvious way is to store it somewhere in the datastore, and have a separate URL that your HTTP client can poll to get the token.

If you can, I'd recommend creating the channel on your GAE frontend before enqueuing the task, then send the token along with the task, and embed the token in the HTTP response to the client, then both the client and the backend can communicate.

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, I ended up using the datastore to have the backend store the token that it creates for the client, which I then  have the front-end retrieve it and respond to the client`s http request.  Once the client had the token created by the backend, it was able to receive the messages from the backend.  Creating the channel token on the front end did not seem to allow the backend to send messages to the client as described in the answer to the question referenced above.

Comment: Creating a channel on the backend seems like the best solution for my application as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448457/whats-the-best-way-to-get-data-back-from-a-task-in-gae-to-form-a-loop-of-task-q). Using a backend was necessary to allow it to exceed the 10 minute deadline, and sending messages from the backend is necessary to notify the client when the data is available.